# C pointer changes without assignment

Tags: c, pointers, raspberry-pi, segmentation-fault, fingerprint

I'm trying to access a fingerprint reader in raspberry pi. I have written a library based on ["Adafruit Fingerprint Sensor Library"](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library). Here is my sample code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int res = wiringPiSetup();
    if (res == -1)
    {
        perror("wiringPiSetup");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* malloc fingerprint_t */
    fingerprint_t *fp = fingerprint_init(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));

    /* this call to fingerprint sensor works fine */
    if (fingerprint_verify_password(fp))
    {
        printf("Found fingerprint sensor\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Did not find fingerprint sensor\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* fp pointer is 0x12008 here */

    while(true)
    {
        uint8_t id;
        printf("type in the ID # you want to save finger print:");
        scanf("%u", &id);
        printf("Enrolling ID #%u\n", id);

        /* same fp pointer is 0x10000 here */

        while (true)
        {
            /* Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault inside this function */
            uint8_t res = get_fingerprint_enroll(fp, id);
            if (!res)
            {
                printf("*****************\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`fp` pointer is OK before first `while` loop but it changes before second `while` without assignment which cause `SIGSEGV` in the program at `get_fingerprint_enroll`. `fingerprint_t` struct is like this:

```
typedef struct _fingerprint_t
{
    uint16_t finger_id;
    uint16_t confidence;
    uint16_t template_count;
    uint32_t password;
    uint32_t address;
    uint32_t fd;
} fingerprint_t;
```

I allocate memory for `fp` in `fingerprint_init` like this:

```
fingerprint_t *fp = (fingerprint_t *) malloc(sizeof(fingerprint_t));
```

I only initialize `password`, `address` and `fd` inside `fingerprint_init`. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `scanf("%u", &id);`, as `id` is `uint8_t` [which is usually represented as `unsigned char`], IMO, you should write `scanf(" %c", &id);`.

`%u` denotes `unsigned int`.

Same goes for `printf("Enrolling ID #%u\n", id);`